# Fundamental group of hyperbolic 2-orbifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group, orbifolds

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a cocompact lattice of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma$ has a natural structure of orbifold. My questions are:

1. What is $\pi_1(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)$?
2. What is $\pi_1^{orb}(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)$?

I know that if $\Gamma$ is torsion free they both coincide with $\Gamma$.

Comment: But the answers are trivial to state: $\pi_1^{orb}(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)\cong\Gamma$, and $\pi_1(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)$ is naturally isomorphic to the quotient of $\Gamma$ by the normal subgroup generated by its torsion elements.